# Turn nested if formula into VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, search, excel-formula

I would like to turn my formula into a macro. I want to look up values on column A and return a different value to column D depending on conditions.

My formula is :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*10*",D2,6)),"word1",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*15*",D2,1)),"word2",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*1*",D2,1)),"word3",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*20*",D2,1)),"word4",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*30*",D2,1)),"word5")))))
```

I need to make sure that search for *1* comes after 10 or 15 so that formula doesn't return word3 for all cells containing "1".

Column A contains a text that is at times is misspelled so the only common value is the numbers. That is why I want to search the numbers within text to return word12345.

Below is an example- I get a different excel file with age name and last name every week and need to fill out the program classification manually.

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗  
║    AGE    ║  NAME   ║ LAST NAME ║ PROGRAM ║  
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣  
║ 10 YE OLD ║ ANNE    ║ BROWN     ║ word1   ║  
║ AGE 10    ║ ALLY    ║ SMITH     ║ word1   ║  
║ 15 YO     ║ MATT    ║ JANES     ║ word2   ║  
║ 15        ║ DENNIS  ║ JOHNSON   ║ word2   ║  
║ 10Y OLD   ║ DIANA   ║ WILLIAMS  ║ word1   ║  
║ 20yr      ║ JORDAN  ║ BROWN     ║ word4   ║  
║ 30 YR OLD ║ MELISSA ║ RODRIGUEZ ║ word5   ║  
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

The data that I need to get the result from is exampled below:

```
10 YE OLD
AGE 10
15 YO
15
10Y OLD
20yr
30 YR OLD
```

Comment: Why not use a lookup table and shorten the formula to a more palatable size?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of data that you have to search and what you're looking for? That would be easier to work with than starting with your formula and working backwards.

Comment: I agree with Scott, use a lookup table.  That way, anyone can update the table and get the result they need.  The vast minority will NOT be able to update the VBA if things need to change.  Abstract the logic from the code where you can.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, I tested it and it worked for me utilizing whole numbers as you stated (10,15,5,1,30,20) and changed it to the "word1" etc. If you were looking for a range, i.e. 1 but less than 10, the select case can be updated. You have to insert your workbook name and extension as well as worksheet name where indicated in the code.

```
Sub Select_Case()
Dim RNG As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TextTest As String
Dim AllColumn As Variant

Set ws = Workbooks("<EnterYourWorkbookName.Extension_Here>").Worksheets("<EnterYourSheetNameHere>")
AllColumn = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 4), ws.Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)) 'assumes heading in row 1 and no breaks in data

    For i = 2 To UBound(AllColumn) 'assumes heading, no headin i = 1
        TextTest = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Set RNG = ws.Cells(i, 4) 'rows then columns if you need to change it later, this should be where you want to output your data
        Select Case TextTest
            Case Is = 10
                RNG = "word1"
            Case Is = 15
                RNG = "word2"
            Case Is = 1
                RNG = "word3"
            Case Is = 20
                RNG = "word4"
            Case Is = 30
                RNG = "word5"
            'Case else (utilize if you have a catch all just in case it is something not predicted)
                'what to do
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Let me know if you need some small tweaks.

Comment: I believe for your case a Select Case is better then a nested if statement, it reads much easier in VBA coding. The order in which you evaluate is not as important either, if you are truly looking for a value.

Comment: @user10986956 Which Column are you evaluating, and which Column did you need the information in? Is the age always displayed with the left 2 characters being age? So 20 YR OLD, or 20 YR, but always 20 is the left 2?